# Help with Sub and Sub-Sub Navigation

Tags: php, navigation, wp-list-pages

I have utilised code from this posting: [Display grandchildren on child and grandchild pages using wp_list_pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152051/display-grandchildren-on-child-and-grandchild-pages-using-wp-list-pages#new-answer?newreg=55355ecea227464ba94826dc17f4d48a) to create my menu here: http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/youth-community/our-work/

As you can see, I have the top level menu showing near the logo, the second level menu showing in side the blue strip and also the 3rd (and 4th) level menus showing in a column the left hand side of the page.

The trouble I'm having is,

1. I have no idea where the top Bullet point 'Pages' is coming from and
   would like to remove this
2. I would like this menu to display as per the order inside the Wordpress menu and not alphabetically.
3. Currently when you hover on these menus, every level pops out, I would like it so they slide out one by one when hovering, not all levels at once...

So here are the bits of code I have - I have this inside the functions.php file:

```
// FUNCTION FOR SETTING UP SUB MENU PAGES

// add hook
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects_sub_menu', 10, 2 );

// filter_hook function to react on sub_menu flag
function my_wp_nav_menu_objects_sub_menu( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
  if ( isset( $args->sub_menu ) ) {
    $root_id = 0;

    // find the current menu item
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
      if ( $menu_item->current ) {
        // set the root id based on whether the current menu item has a parent or not
        $root_id = ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) ? $menu_item->menu_item_parent : $menu_item->ID;
        break;
      }
    }

    // find the top level parent
    if ( ! isset( $args->direct_parent ) ) {
      $prev_root_id = $root_id;
      while ( $prev_root_id != 0 ) {
        foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
          if ( $menu_item->ID == $prev_root_id ) {
            $prev_root_id = $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
            // don't set the root_id to 0 if we've reached the top of the menu
            if ( $prev_root_id != 0 ) $root_id = $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
            break;
          } 
        }
      }
    }

    $menu_item_parents = array();
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $item ) {
      // init menu_item_parents
      if ( $item->ID == $root_id ) $menu_item_parents[] = $item->ID;

      if ( in_array( $item->menu_item_parent, $menu_item_parents ) ) {
        // part of sub-tree: keep!
        $menu_item_parents[] = $item->ID;
      } else if ( ! ( isset( $args->show_parent ) && in_array( $item->ID, $menu_item_parents ) ) ) {
        // not part of sub-tree: away with it!
        unset( $sorted_menu_items[$key] );
      }
    }

    return $sorted_menu_items;
  } else {
    return $sorted_menu_items;
  }
}

// FUNCTION FOR SETTING UP SUB-SUB MENU PAGES

/** Get Top Most Page ID and Return it **/
function get_ancestor(){
    global $post;
    $id = 0;

    if(is_object($post)){
        $id = $post->ID;

        if($post->post_parent){
            $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
            $root = count($ancestors)-1;
            $id = $ancestors[$root];
        }
    } 
    else if(is_singular('post') || is_archive() || (is_home() && !is_front_page())){
        $id = get_option('page_for_posts');
    }

    return $id;
}
```

Also, here's the code in my template page I'm using to display the 3rd level menu only - as its just this 3rd level I have a problem with:

```
<?php $id = get_ancestor(); // Hold Top Most Page ID ?>

        <?php if($post->post_parent != 0) : /** IF we're NOT on a Top Level Page **/ ?>
            <ul>
                <?php 
                    $parentID = ($post->post_parent == $id) ? $post->ID : $post->post_parent;
                    wp_list_pages("child_of=$parentID&depth=2"); 
                ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
```